# Uploading document error

Tags: sharepoint-server

While uploading the file got an error 
"We're sorry, someone updated the server copy and it's not possible to upload your changes now".

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the name of your file to something personal then try again. It may be because you are trying to upload a file which another has locked for editing.